# Does the latest stable pygame release work with python2.7?

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Like the subject says: Does the latest stable pygame release work with python2.7?

I've got both versions installed on my OSX Snow Leopard, but `import pygame` only works on python2.6 - That's the official distro which is 2.6.6, not the pre-installed one which is 2.6.1).

And if it does work, how can I make it work on my machine? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you installed it for 2.6 and so it is residing in 2.6's library directory. Install it in 2.7's library directory and you should be good to go. I don't know OSX so I can't help with the details but a little bit of googling shouldn't be too hard. The problem is that the two python installations have distinct import paths.